# Spring set bean name with @Named

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, javabeans

I use javax standard annotation `@Named` for defining beans in spring4. To set the bean name I could tried `@Named("MyBean")` but it did not change the bean name.

I used spring `Component` annotation `@Component("MyBean")` and it worked fine.

Is it possible to set the bean name by using  `@Named`

The bean is defined asL

```
@Named("myBean") //This not
@Component("myBean") //This works
@Scope("session")
public class User implements HttpSessionBindingListener, Serializable {
```

The `application.context` is

```
<context:component-scan base-package="foo.bar" />
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Can you please provide more information about your problem (like the applicationContext.xml, if any)? Maybe it was another problem.

Comment: Please see my update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree to what @fabian has said. You can use @Named annotation to set the bean name. If bean name doesn't matches, it falls back to auto-wiring by type.

I tried couple of examples. They worked for me.

AppConfig.java

```
package com.named;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class AppConfig {

}
```

NamedService.java

```
package com.named;

import javax.inject.Named;

@Named("namedTestDependency")
public class NamedService {

    public void namedMethod(){
        System.out.println("Named method");
    }

}
```

NamedServiceTest.java

```
package com.named;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import com.named.AppConfig;
import com.named.NamedService;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=AppConfig.class)
public class NamedServiceTest {

    //Matched by name of dependency
    @Autowired
    private NamedService namedTestDependency;

    //Falls back to auto-wiring by type
    @Autowired
    private NamedService noDeclaration;

    @Test
    public void testAutowiring(){
        assertNotNull(namedTestDependency);
        assertNotNull(noDeclaration);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks but you have used `@Autowired` annotation instead of `@Inject`. Did test that it works with `@inject` too ?!

Comment: I tried the code with @Inject in the test class. It worked fine.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6885eb966876bd6704324838667e03a8 .  Please take a look at the code.

Comment: Although still it is not working with me session scope object,  but the code seems it should work and I will try more, Thanks!